# Geb drive method

Tags: groovy, geb, browser-automation

I'm trying to learn how to use Geb and I'm getting an error. Could you guys help me out?

I'm trying to use the drive method but it is not working. I've tested a few of the other Browser's methods and they work all right. Just the drive method is giving me trouble.

I've checked the API and googled around but didn't find anything helpful. The strange thing is the fact that I don't get an error message. There is no Exception. I'm running the code on Groovy's console and Firefox just chills for a while and then the execution finishes.

Geb 0.9.2, FirefoxDriver and JDK 7

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import geb.Browser

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

public class MyTest {

    Browser browser;

    void test(){
        browser = new Browser(driver: new FirefoxDriver())
        browser.go "http://www.google.com" // this works
        browser.$("div button", name: "btnK").text() == "Google Search" // this works
        browser.drive { // WHY U NO WORK?!!
            go "http://www.google.com"
        }

    }

}

x = MyTest()
x.test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `drive()` is a [static method](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#the_drive_method) and it's designed to be used in scripts where you don't instantiate a browser instance. You have to decide - you either use a browser instance or the `Browser.drive {}` method. Yo cannot do both.

You might also consider using one of the [integrations with testing frameworks](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/testing.html#spock_junit__testng) - by doing so you'll get Geb to manage a browser instance for you.